# Comments or remarks in an xcopy exclude file

Tags: comments, xcopy, remarks

I know how xcopy works, but is it possible to add comments to your exclude files? Something like this:

```
.pdb
.xml
.config
Some.dll /* excluded because ... */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we did it:

```
.pdb
.xml
.config
 /* excluded because ... */
Some.dll
```

Maybe a no-brainer for some, but I thought there might have been a default way of commenting in excluded files. Maybe xcopy even searches for a file with filename '/* excluded because ... */, but it works for us.